# How to receive push notifications from Firebase cloud messaging on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been able to send push notification from Firebase (Firebase cloud messaging) into my android application.

I wanted to know if I can build an app in c# (.net) that will receive notification from firebase as in Android application.

So far, I found examples that send the notification but none of them actually have demonstrated how to received the notification in c# desktop application.

If there are any documentation on receiving notification or any code snippet will be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is no support for *receiving* FCM notifications in a .NET desktop application.

Answer (score 11):

There is no support for *receiving* FCM notifications in a .NET desktop application. There is no FCM SDK for the platform, and the wire protocol is undocumented.

There *is* support for [receiving FCM notifications on a Xamarin app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos) on Android or iOS, but that doesn't seem to be what you're after.

Comment: thanks. Yeah I was hoping if I could find one for .Net.

Comment: Were there any changes regarding this, since the last year? Specifically - is it possible to receive FCM notifications on desktop applications now?

Comment: As commented on your new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248834/using-firesharp-for-windows-desktop-push-notifications-only) about the topic, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet
It is written by Google and available in NuGet packages in Visual Studio

Comment: Does it handle incoming notifications. I guess it's for mange and sending notifications but not receive!