# How to send notifications from php server side to Visual Basic client side like android

Tags: php, android, vb.net, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send a notification from php server side to Visual Basic or do I have to synchronize the server side database with the local database every x minutes to check for any changes?

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
include 'send_notification.php';
if (!$conn) {
    $response["response"] = false;
    $response["log"] = mysqli_error($conn);
    $response["exception"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $pricing = json_decode($_POST['pricing'], true);
    $user = json_decode($_POST['user'], true);

    // Here update database....

    $company_token = getCompanyToken($user["id"]); // Find company token from MySql database to send FCM to Android Client


    sendNotification($company_token); // Send Notification To Android...It works fine..

    // Same notification to Visual Basic Windows Client...
    // Help!! Synchronize local database with the server or is there any other way?


    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only official SDKs for **receiving** messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging are for Android, iOS, and Web clients. Unless you are targeting one of these platforms, there is no SDK for receiving messages on VB.Net.

Also see:

- [How to receive push notifications from Firebase cloud messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507588/how-to-receive-push-notifications-from-firebase-cloud-messaging)
- [Is it possible to receive FCM in .NET Core App (e.g. WPF Core client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055063/is-it-possible-to-receive-fcm-in-net-core-app-e-g-wpf-core-client)

Comment: Ok, I imagined this but there is no other way to send changes to Visual Basic without waiting for database synchronization?